# to_date in selectexpr of pyspark is truncating date time to year by default. how to avoid this?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where I derive the year to be loaded and then have to load the first day and last day of that year in date format to a table.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
boy = str(nxt_yr)+'01-01'
eoy = str(nxt_yr)+'12-31'

df_final = df_demo.selectExpr("to_date('{}','yyyy-MM-dd') as strt_dt".format(boy),"to_date('{}','yyyy-MM-dd') as end_dt".format(eoy))

spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy = LEGACY")
df_final.show(1)

this is giving me 2023-01-01 in both the fields in date datatype.

Is this expected behavior and if yes is there any workaround?


Note: I tried hardcoding the date as 2022-11-30 also in the code but still received the beginning of the year in the output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working as expected , additionally you are missing a `-` within your dates you create for conversions

```
nxt_yr = 2022

boy = str(nxt_yr)+'-01-01'
#                  |                   
#                 /|\
#                  |
#                  |

eoy = str(nxt_yr)+'-12-31'

sql.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy = LEGACY")

sql.sql(f"""                       
SELECT
     to_date('{boy}','yyyy-MM-dd') as strt_dt
    ,to_date('{eoy}','yyyy-MM-dd') as end_dt

"""
).show()

+----------+----------+
|   strt_dt|    end_dt|
+----------+----------+
|2022-01-01|2022-12-31|
+----------+----------+
```